# How to turn off search highlights in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-search

After a recent Windows update, my search bar looks ugly:

[image]

The "Yellowstone National Park" text and that image is annoying. How do I disable them?

This is how it previously looked:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on the taskbar.
2. Go to *Search* and turn off *Show search highlights*.

   [image]
3. Now the search box is back to normal!

   [image]

---

This feature is known as [search highlights](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/group-configuration-search-highlights-in-windows/ba-p/3263989) and it began rolling out to Windows 10 users on March 22, 2022.

> You have control over the search highlights experience if you prefer not to see this. To turn it off or back on, right click on your taskbar, select Search and then select or clear “Show search highlights.”