# Why is there a tennis ball in my Windows search bar?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Why is my Windows search bar showing a tennis ball?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Right-click on the taskbar, and in the context menu that appears, select News and interests > Turn off.    That should do it   .....    https://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/689049/how-turn-off-news-interests-windows-10-taskbar/#:~:text=The%20setting%20you're%20looking,News%20and%20interests%20%3E%20Turn%20off.

Comment: @John its already turned off

Comment: Try the following:    Right click task bar, Go to Search , then  uncheck "Show Search Highlights"  ....  See if that helps.  News appeared again for some (not all) users.

Comment: What, you dont play tennis? lol.

Comment: @John - Thanks, exactly what I was looking for and it worked for me.

Comment: @John - actually, after about 30 minutes it re-appeared again :(

Comment: @Moab I do play tennis

Comment: Then that is why it is there! Microsoft knows everything.....

Comment: @Moab that's scary

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/1716527

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why is my Windows search bar showing a tennis ball?

It is likely that is some important news about tennis or an ongoing major tennis tournament in your area. You can click on the tennis ball to find out more.

Microsoft has rolled out a "search highlights" feature for Windows 10 users:

> Search highlights shows related content for a search when a user hovers or clicks on an illustration that appears within the Windows search box, which is located on the Windows taskbar at the bottom of the screen. The search highlights feature will show things like images associated with a search, as well as "daily content like word of the day, Microsoft Rewards offers, trending searches, and more," according to this [Windows 10 Insider program post](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/03/14/releasing-windows-10-build-19044-1618-to-release-preview-channel/)

Source: [Microsoft Bringing Search Highlights Feature to Windows 10 and Windows 11 Users -- Redmondmag.com](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2022/03/25/microsoft-bringing-search-highlights-feature-to-windows-10--and-windows-11-users.aspx)

> The taskbar search box and search home will periodically update with content, including fun illustrations, which help you discover more, be connected, and stay productive. Search highlights will present notable and interesting moments of what’s special about each day—like holidays, anniversaries, and other educational moments in time both globally and in your region. To see more details at a glance, hover or click on the illustration in the search box.

Source [Releasing Windows 10 Build 19044.1618 to Release Preview Channel | Windows Insider Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/03/14/releasing-windows-10-build-19044-1618-to-release-preview-channel/)

.

Comment: Saw it myself and couldn't find the name nor how to disable it.