# Where can I find Windows Search Highlights images?

Tags: windows-10, pictures

Windows has released Search Highlights for Windows 10 and 11. So there are small images in the search bar; here's the one for today (2022 June 5) since it's world environment day:
[image]

Where do these images come from? Is there a list of the images Windows has used?

Comment: @John I am not asking about how to disable these images. I want to know their source (as images).

Comment: @John OK; I would also like to know if I can get a collection of these images. I have edited the title to reflect this.

Comment: Is it possible to disable these images?  I use my computer for business, not for Microsoft's time wasting rubbish.

Comment: @KevinP. According to Google search results, it is possible to disable, though I have not verified these myself. On Windows 10: https://superuser.com/questions/1716527/how-to-turn-off-search-highlights-in-windows-10 On Windows 11: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-search-highlights-in-windows-11.5735/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These images are fetched from bing.com.
In order to get todays DSB (Dynamic Search Bar) content, you need to fetch `https://www.bing.com/dsb?setmkt=en-US&dsbschemaversion=1.1` with the following headers

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0; Cortana 1.15.0.0;10.0.22621.1265) like Gecko
```

My archiver for these broke a while ago, and I haven't had the time to properly fix it yet, but you can find an older archive of DSB images over on https://gitlab.com/bignutty/dsb

Comment: What happened to your repo? I absolutely love it when ppl like yourself archive such data :)

Comment: I've seen that somebody else edited my post for me, I (somewhat) recently changed my gitlab handle to bignutty, you can find the repo over at https://gitlab.com/bignutty/dsb now!

Comment: @bignutty, the bing.com URL you had provided has gone broken. If you've managed to update your scraper, could you please share the new details for fetching?

Comment: Hey, fetching the DSB now mandates you specify the schema version. I've gone ahead and updated my original post to reflect these changes.
edit: odd, through my testing it seems that the old URL should also still work fine, are you sure you're not doing something wrong on your end?

Comment: @bignutty, you're right; I was making a mistake. I don't know which cause I hadn't checked in my code anywhere, but this time around, it works with and without the schema version. Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that these images have to be stored somewhere on the PC.. WHERE is that location??  I think THAT is what the OP wanted to know.. (and me also)

Actually I found where the images are located (at least temporarily)

AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\ShellFeeds

in there are .svg files (not sure if always named the same) right now mine are GLEAM-DARM.svg and GLEAM-LIGHT.svg

Answer (score 2):

Search Highlights is Windows feature designed by Microsoft to help users discover related content and interesting information of what's special about each day like holidays, anniversaries, and other moments in time both globally and in your region.

Here is a non official [site](https://highlights.cyclic.app) where you can find the collection of Windows Search Highlights (SVG images) categorized by Months and Years.

New images added everyday at 00h:02m UTC+14.

Answer (score -1):

I found the image at the following path:

C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\INetCache\TJNEIN26\th[1].svg

You can find it at a similar path.
Replace YourUsername in the path with your username.
Random string in the path may be different in your system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).