# How do I get rid of the AI bing search option on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, bing

Not sure when this fun feature nobody asked for appeared, but I'm not fond of it and find it useless 100% of the time.

[image]

Does anyone know how it can be removed or hidden?

[image]

They should really take a hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off search highlights in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1716527/how-to-turn-off-search-highlights-in-windows-10). The icon that is displayed has changed several times in the last 2 years since Search Highlights was introduced.  The Bing AI icon is just the most recent and was introduced in March 2023.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open "Settings"
2. Click "Privacy & Security" [[sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)]
3. Under the “Windows permissions” section, click the “Search permissions” setting.
4. Under the “More settings” section, turn off the “Show Search highlights” toggle switch to disable Bing Chat AI.

Comment: @JoeMoore updated

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: I had to vote this up mainly for the *'ironic'* use of [sic]! ... [sic]!