# Remove Bing and Chat Icons from Windows 11 Start Menu Search Results

Tags: windows-11, start-menu

How can I remove the items highlighted in yellow from the search dialog in the Windows 11 start menu?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of the AI bing search option on Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1778789/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-ai-bing-search-option-on-windows-11)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so I figured out a way with the registry editor. Also I don't consider this a "hack" like one of the comments suggests as registry edits are pretty dang easy to add/remove and highly unlikely to "wreck" my machine.

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`

1. Add `DWORD DisableSearchBoxSuggestions = 1`
2. Restart

[image]

---

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the one that finally worked for me. Google's littered with articles about just disabling the "Search Highlights" setting, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: I didn't have the folder `explorer`. Right click on the folder `Windows` to add a key named `explorer`.

Comment: In my case, the entry `Explorer` did not exist in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\`. However, adding the DWORD in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch worked like a charm.