# Windows 11 search only local programs

Tags: windows-11

I am not certain if I need to edit the "search and indexing" in windows 11 but, I cannot stand pushing the windows button typing a programs name and the first result is an internet result.

I only want my local programs like in Windows 7. It has all been down hill from there Microsoft. (10 seemed ok)

Yes I can "apps: Program name", but I would like to only see results that exist on my machine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Windows 11 is not (and never will be) Windows 7. Click on Search, type one or two characters, click on Local (documents likely) and search. It has nothing to do with indexing and you can click, type 2, click in 2 seconds.  Nothing to lose sleep over.

Comment: See https://pureinfotech.com/disable-search-web-results-windows-11/#:~:text=To%20disable%20web%20search%20in,File%20Explorer%20search%20box%E2%80%9D%20policy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Bing and Chat Icons from Windows 11 Start Menu Search Results](https://superuser.com/questions/1782561/remove-bing-and-chat-icons-from-windows-11-start-menu-search-results)

Comment: R and R, seems I already did this. I guess now it is searching "files content": Documents, files, etc.

Comment: I'm with you on this. I absolutely HATE when I'm trying to find some standard Windows utility, and I reflexively click on a match only to have it pop up a browser. It wouldn't be so bad if all the result types weren't mixed together in the same list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under settings > Privacy & security > Searching Windows

Set "Find in Files" to "classic" not "Enhanced"