# How to remove bing AI search from Windows 11 search bar?

Tags: windows, windows-11, bing

I already changed the "search permissions" settings, including the "more settings" ones.
I have also uninstalled chrome by running some commands i found.

And still, when i open the windows search window, i am met with the bing logo and the "search with chat" icon.  Please help me get rid of it.

Comment: This might be useful https://youtu.be/2v3k9SCnIuM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Bing and Chat Icons from Windows 11 Start Menu Search Results](https://superuser.com/questions/1782561/remove-bing-and-chat-icons-from-windows-11-start-menu-search-results)

Answer (score 0):

Several options :

**Disable Bing Button in Taskbar Search**

- Run *Settings > Privacy & Security > Search Permissions*
- Scroll down to the "More Settings"
- Turn off "Search Highlights" option.

This will instantly disable the Bing button in the search box
in the taskbar.

[image]

**Disable the Bing logo in the taskbar**

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar*
- Under Taskbar items, select "Search icon and label" from
  the drop-down menu.

Now have the plain search box in the taskbar, without extra
icons or images.

[image]

Source :
[How to disable the Bing button in the taskbar search on Windows 11](https://winaero.com/disable-bing-button-taskbar-search/).